# How to change styling of a specific div onhover of another element when divs share an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple rows with 3 divs per row. Each div consists of two rows; in the first row a picture is displayed, in the second row a description is shown. HTML is like this:

```
<div id="row">
    <div id="block1">
        <div id="block1-top"><a><img></a></div>
        <div id="block1-bottom">Text here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="block2">
        <div id="block2-top"><a><img></a></div>
        <div id="block2-bottom">Text here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="block3">
        <div id="block3-top"><a><img></a></div>
        <div id="block3-bottom">Text here</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="row">
    <div id="block1">
        <div id="block1-top"><a><img></a></div>
        <div id="block1-bottom">Text here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="block2">
        <div id="block2-top"><a><img></a></div>
        <div id="block2-bottom">Text here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="block3">
        <div id="block3-top"><a><img></a></div>
        <div id="block3-bottom">Text here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some CSS:

```
#block1, #block2, #block3
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #154494;
}

#block1-bottom, #block2-bottom, #block3-bottom
{
color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

I want the color of the text in the bottom of the block to change to #FEB90D on hover of the parent div. So for example when hovering over block1, I want the text color of block1-bottom to change into #FEB90D. I found a script which does this for me:

```
$(function() {
  $('#block1').hover(function() {
    $('#block1-bottom').css('color', '#FEB90D');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('#block1-bottom').css('color', '#FFFFFF');
  });
});
```

However, this only works for the first block of the first row. I think this is because the id's of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd blocks have the same name and the script cannot figure out on which block to apply the script.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this, without changing all the divs id's? I have 11 rows in total so using separate names for each div is not really an option in my opinion. So basically, the scripts needs to change the color of the second child of the hovered div.

Comment: `id` values must be unique.

Comment: Check the demo here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35163293/3733816

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to do this with CSS

```css
.block1 > .block1-bottom {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.block1:hover > .block1-bottom {
  color: #FEB90D;
}
```

```html
<div class='block1'>
  <p class='block1-top'>This is paragraph 1</p>
  <p class='block1-bottom'>This is paragraph 2</p>
</div>
```

IDs should be unique anyways. If you do it in jQuery, it should look like this.

```
$(function() {
    $('.block1').on("mouseover", function() {
        $('.block1-bottom').css('color', '#FEB90D');
    }).on("mouseout", function() {
        $('.block1-bottom').css('color', '#FFFFFF');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using id for more than one element. Change those ids for classes and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ids should be unique. So add necessary classes and use class selector. So code is similar to below

```
$('.row .box').hover(function() {
      $(this).find(".boxbottom").css('color', '#FEB90D');    
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour    
    $(this).find(".boxbottom").css('color', '#FFFFFF');
  });
```

Here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/afnhjdjy/

Answer (score 0):

After you clean up your duplicate IDs problem, you can do this without javascript at all:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block-top"><a><img></a></div>
        <div class="block-bottom">Text here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block-top"><a><img></a></div>
        <div class="block-bottom">Text here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block:hover .block-bottom {color: #FEB90D}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this situation:

> I want the color of the text in the bottom of the block to change to #FEB90D on hover of the parent div

You may simply use:

```
.block:hover .block-bottom{
    color: #FEB90D;
}
```